# Two drop downs with same value. If user selects a value in first drop down then that value must be disable in second drop down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I'm new to angularjs. I've 2 drop downs with same values in html. Here I want whenever user selects a value in first drop down then that value want to disable in second drop down.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

app.controller('queryCntrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.names = [ "Ali", "Raj", "Ahm", "Sbm", "Lvy" ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<title>Fund Transfer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="queryCntrl">

 From  <select ng-model="selectedName"
  ng-options="x for x in names">
 </select>
</div>
<div>
 <br> To <select ng-model="selectedName"
  ng-options="x for x in names">
 </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `disable when` expression to disable options.

```
From
<select ng-model="selectedName" 
  ng-options="name disable when (name.indexOf(selectedName1) > -1) for name in names">
</select>
<br> To
<select ng-model="selectedName1" 
  ng-options="name disable when (name.indexOf(selectedName) > -1) for name in names">
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SJiAr5g1k2RJvAyozPQB?p=preview)

You could change condition to `selectedName == name` considering single select.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less confusing way,

## update: this works as expected

use `disable when` then `expression` in `ng-options`. i found it on [angular.js documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

something like this,

```
 From  <select ng-model="selectedName"
    ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

<br> To <select ng-model="selectedName1"
  ng-options="x disable when selectedName==x  for x in names " >
</select>
```

[here is a working code](https://jsfiddle.net/Miqe/a6wcda2L/2/)

#### Update: fixed the link to working code

#### Note: i noticed you placed your `ng-controller` on the wrong place, `ng-controller` must wrap the second `select` field too(`body` is the ideal place).

Comment: thanks @PankajParkar i thought the question was something else!

Comment: OP wants to disable value inside dropdown of other `select` box, if other dropdown has that value selected.. Please look at above plunker.